# Countdown array of numbers in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of numbers: `$arr=[25,10,12]`.

I want to create another array with several arrays that are a "countdown" of the original array such that the final array (in the new array) has only zeros like so `[0,0,0]`;

I expect an output like so:

```
[25,10,12]
[25,10,11]
[25,10,10]
   :
[25,10,0]
   :
/* An element "resets" if the first element is not yet zero */ 
[25,9,12] 
[25,9,11]
   :
[10,10,12]
[10,10,11]
   :
[0,0,1]
[0,0,0]
```

Comment: Can we see what you have tried so far ?

Comment: How specifically do you intend the countdown to work? Do they countdown all at once or one-by-one from right to left? How does the third number go from zero back up to nine?

Comment: Yes @showdev. The countdown starts from right to left. It then resets back to the original number if the first element is not zero..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by going over each number (from left to right) [recursively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)), this will make the number furthest to the right do it's counting first.

But instead of inputting the same original array each time we do make a copy of it, inject the new number at the index and use that as our new input for the next recursion.

To not get into an infinite depth we of course also have to keep track of the length of the input and check the depth (aka which index we're currently going over in the array), if it's index we're trying to check is the same as the length of the input, we know that this is a new value to store, otherwise we iterate towards zero and go deeper in the recursion.

```
$input = [15, 25, 10];
$output =[];

function recursive($input, &$output, $index = 0) {
    if ($index == count($input)) {
        $output[] = $input;
    }
    else {
        $newInput = $input;
        for ($i = $input[$index]; $i >= 0; $i--) {
            $newInput[$index] = $i;
            recursive($newInput, $output, $index+1);
        }
    }
}

recursive($input, $output);

print_r($output);
```

Check out the result [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bdffd3075271b94deabecd4678ae012297a9d536)